# Scrollcontainer with fixed element inside not scrollable on fixed element

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have a container with a fixed height and overflow scroll. 
Inside I have a header and content which is overflowing the container.

When my mouse is on the content the container scrolls. But when I am on the Header the scroll event of the container is not triggered.

How can I trigger the scrollevent everywhere on the container, even on the header?

I created a example to see the behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0x2oxw8x3

I am using React with styled-components, so I can not use Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Just use pointer-events: none

```js
const Header = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  pointer-events: none; // add this
`;
```

Comment: Yep, this works, but on my real header I have some links and buttons, and then they arent working anymore...

Comment: Try to just use position: sticky; instead of position: fixed